# how to use manytomany field with self?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use manytomany field but I'm so confused.
what i'm trying to achive is; inside food category i want to show links for fries, steak,potato category pages.
I'm trying to do it like this;

```
class Category(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    related_cat = models.ManyToManyField('self')



{% if category.related_cat %}

{{category.related_cat.name}}

{% endif %}
```

But this shows none...
I'm so confused with this...can someone please clarify and direct me what I should do?

Comment: Why ManyToMany? If every subcategory can only have one parent, you should use a `ForeignKey` instead.

Comment: @Selcuk thing I'm trying to do is,  display child categories in parent category....yeah I guess I should use foreignkey here....hmmm I'll try it

Comment: Note that in that case `related_cat` wil give you the parent category, while `category_set.all` will return all the sub categories. It might be easier for you to read your code in the future if you rename `related_cat` to something like `parent_category` if you go with the ForeignKey method.

Comment: @Selcuk yeah thanks...that's where I'm having a problem with..when I do it like that, it onlys shows parent category which is not what I'm trying to do.(it's the opposite)...so I should do {{category_set.all}} in the template?

Comment: @Selcuk yeah you are right...I should put that as parent_category...I was thinking the other way

Comment: Yes. Also see @monkut's answer for a detailed explanation.

Comment: @Selcuk I'm so confused right now...so with foreignkey, sub can have only one parent but monkut's answer is for  when sub can have multiple parent?

Comment: Yes, @monkut explains how to do it with the existing (ManyToMany) relation, while I suggested you to change it to a one-to-many (ForeignKey) relation. Whichever you choose depends on your use case (if you need multiple parents for a sub-category or not).

Comment: @Selcuk, ok sorry just one more thing,{{category_set.all}}should be {{category.parent_category_.all}} no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108684/discussion-between-selcuk-and-mike-braa).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your field, `related_cat`, is a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField), it's reference can contain more than *1 object*.

To access the *objects* in a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) try:

```
{% if category.related_cat %}

    {% for related_category in category.related_cat.all %}
        {{related_category.name}}
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

For other examples:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships

Comment: I was just doing some test and I got a problem
when I made a sports category
and then picked baseball, football, basketball as related_cat
then in sports category the following are being displayed
but even in baseball, football, basketball page
the related_cat are being displayed
I want football--->sports but not sports---->football

Comment: can you detect the problem?

Comment: sounds like a data structure issue.  You may not want to allow self referencing... It can be hard to find the right data structure, and may take a bit of work.